# How do I display buttons and text under eachother with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to display buttons and some text with javafx but it whont work it just displays over eachother in the middle of the screen:

[image: window]

I have been trying to use vbox and ive also tried to use hbox but both dont change how it looks when i run it

(when i run it i get no erors)
(also im using vs code if that has anything to say)

Here is my code so far:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // buttons

        VBox vboxBtn = new VBox();
        vboxBtn.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vboxBtn.setSpacing(10);

        Button btnRoom = new Button("changeRoom");
        Button btnMap = new Button("changeMap");

        vboxBtn.getChildren().addAll(btnRoom, btnMap);


        // text
        
        VBox vboxTxt = new VBox();
        vboxTxt.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vboxTxt.setSpacing(10);

        Text txtRoom = new Text("Room");
        Text txtMap = new Text("Map");
        
        vboxTxt.getChildren().addAll(btnRoom, btnMap);

        String currentRoom = "None";
        String currentMap = "None";

        // button for switching maps
        btnMap.setText("Change the map");
        // button click
        btnMap.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello world");
            }
        });

        // text for maps
        txtMap.setText("Map: " + currentMap);


        // button for switching rooms
        btnRoom.setText("Hello world");
        // button click
        btnRoom.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello world");
            }
        });

        // text
        txtRoom.setText("Room: " + currentRoom);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btnRoom);
        root.getChildren().add(btnMap);
        root.getChildren().add(txtRoom);
        root.getChildren().add(txtMap);
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are adding butons and txts to the pane instead of Vboxes and Hboxes.

I believe you want them on a 4x4 grid, to do that you need to add your virtual boxes to a hbox then add that hbox to a pane, or u could use a grid.

Or you could set their locations, I dont know if this is possible with code, but you can do that in screenbuilder.

PS: check out screenbuilder for javafx.

Comment: thanks. i tested the first thing u said and it worked. now imme try scenebuilder (igoogled screenbuilder qnd scene builder cam up first so imma try it)